# Does this type of organization make sense if it's all people have known?

Tags: society, government, dystopia, finances

These were taken from a bulletted list, so sorry if the grammar is weird.

...They do all this to keep the wealth and luxuries of the world within the city, so that no one inside is poor; it is a utopia; they don’t have to deal with//think about poverty or starvation anywhere else in the world

Since everyone is rich, they are also the ones being persecuted, but there is not much incentive for crime

Everyone gets free food, drinks, clothing, and housing, but each person also gets an allotted amount of currency that they can spend on more exotic goods

Jobs/functions are optional; they are more like hobbies; you don't have to do anything

Exotic goods are made in mini bio-terras that are highly guarded

Algorithms determine what the people want

Revolts or uprisings almost never occur, but if they do their requests are met unless it involved the outside or the past

Comment: So where do they get all the goods and services from if there's no incentive? Do they have a robot servant class, a human slave servant class, or nothing at all?

Comment: @Halfthawed I'm thinking that the plants and animals are maintained by robots or people who enjoy farming. and all the people in the society are encouraged to take a 'career' mainly because fame or popularity is the base social construct.

Comment: I'm now reminded of the planet Solaria from the Asimov novel *The Naked Sun*. It has a similar society to the one you describe, why not give it a read?

Comment: Can you expand on "algorithms determine what the people want?"  The way I read that, people's desires are controlled by a computer algorithm... which creates a fantastic series of dystopias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### What you depict can indeed exist with our level of technology. However, unfortunately we are mammals.

The [utopian world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utopia) (perhaps entitled [post-scarcity economy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-scarcity_economy)) is indeed one to aim for. But what many do not realise is that we can achieve this with our level of technology right now - we don't need to wait.

The problem is of our own making, perhaps harking back to our origins as competitive mammals: we crave and desire to be not just better versions of ourselves, but better than others we meet. But why, if we can have anything we want? The issue is not that we can have anything, but that we can't have everything.

As mammals, we would want and covet things or people that are hard to get, solely to enable us to get them.

So - in parallel to your utopia which I think is an admirable goal - you need to establish a system of competitiveness to enable us to satisfy our human nature. It could be a grading spectrum, rank structure, or gaming culture over the top as a layer to enable our competitive nature to express itself.

There are many more things to flesh out in your world, problems to solve, human nature to satisfy, but this would be a start.

Comment: So my story is told from the point of view of the people outside of this system. There is a city and there are outsiders, and the majority of both know nothing about eachother. Any tips there?

Comment: @AlexandraEagle This is where stories get juicy and what I love! Of course a clash of cultures is the best way I think to tell a story, the juxtaposition is what provides such a setting with so much material. I would look at every facet of what is different between the two cultures, not just in the mechanics of what is different, but in how different they think and feel.